# Opening multiple H2 Consoles for Corda Nodes

Tags: h2, corda

I would like to be able to query the h2 in memory database for each Corda node concurrently, but am unable to do so currently.  Does anybody have a workaround?

Comment: did you follow this guide: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/node-database-access-h2.html ? What do you mean by "concurrently"?

Answer (score 0):

Like Alessandro described, you're going to want to follow this guide (https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/node-database-access-h2.html) to connect to your nodes.

It shouldn't make a difference how many connections you make to it or which nodes. The H2 db should work like you expect.